# How to avoid BackingStoreException at the time of installation using install4j

Tags: install4j

If user don't have permissions to the ".java/.systemPrefs" directory, at the time of installation it is showing below warning and stack trace.

Is there any way to suppress these warnings?

WARNING: Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/.java/.systemPrefs/com/install4j/installations/prefs.tmp (Permission denied)

Comment: What Java version do you use?

Comment: I'm using java 1.6.0_30. If it is Java version specific issue, I will try upgrading the Java

Comment: Please try with java 7. We do try to supress this message, but the code that mutes the logger is somewhat version-specific